# Get 3 next working dates, skip weekends and holidays

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get the next 3 days using php but if the date is a weekend or a defined holiday I would like to skip that date.

For example if the date is Monday, December 23, 2013
My holiday dates are `array('2013-12-24', '2013-12-25');`
The script would return

```
Monday, December 23, 2013
Thursday, December 26, 2013
Friday, December 27, 2013
Monday, December 30, 2013
```

Her is my current code:

```
$arr_date = explode('-', '2013-12-23');
$counter = 0;
for ($iLoop = 0; $iLoop < 4; $iLoop++)
{
    $dayOfTheWeek = date("N", mktime(0, 0, 0, $arr_date[1], $arr_date[2]+$counter, $arr_date[0]));
    if ($dayOfTheWeek == 6) { $counter += 2; }
    $date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $arr_date[1], $arr_date[2]+$counter, $arr_date[0]));
    echo $date;
    $counter++;
}
```

The issue I am having is I am not sure to how to even go about excluding holidays dates.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20683562/250259) has a lot of logic you can use for this

Comment: OK. So what have you attempted so far?  What is not working?

Comment: Also, please show the code you are currently working on as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @NobleUplift that was a tpying error, it was supposed to be a `23`

Comment: I am putting the code together now.

Comment: I know I know. I couldn't help but point it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `DateTime` to recurse over the next days and have a string comparison check to see if the next generated day belongs in the holiday or weekend arrays using `in_array`

```
$holidays = array('12-24', '12-25');
$weekend = array('Sun','Sat');
$date = new DateTime('2013-12-23');
$nextDay = clone $date;
$i = 0; // We have 0 future dates to start with
$nextDates = array(); // Empty array to hold the next 3 dates
while ($i < 3)
{
    $nextDay->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // Add 1 day
    if (in_array($nextDay->format('m-d'), $holidays)) continue; // Don't include year to ensure the check is year independent
    // Note that you may need to do more complicated things for special holidays that don't use specific dates like "the last Friday of this month"
    if (in_array($nextDay->format('D'), $weekend)) continue;
    // These next lines will only execute if continue isn't called for this iteration
    $nextDates[] = $nextDay->format('Y-m-d');
    $i++;
}
```

Using the suggestion of `isset()` for `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`:

```
$holidays = array('12-24' => '', '12-25' => '');
$weekend = array('Sun' => '','Sat' => '');
$date = new DateTime('2013-12-23');
$dayInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$nextDay = clone $date;
$i = 0;
$nextDates = array();
while ($i < 3)
{
    $nextDay->add($dayInterval);
    if (isset($holidays[$nextDay->format('m-d')])) continue;
    if (isset($weekend[$nextDay->format('D')])) continue;
    $nextDates[] = $nextDay->format('Y-m-d');
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, was even really easy to modify to work with my database! Thank you.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh no problem - I've added some commenting. You may have to also find an elegant way to check on holidays with non-specific dates like [Victoria Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Day) (if you were Canadian, for example)

Comment: isn't that as simple as saying `if (in_array($nextDay->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays))`?

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh You could do that, but then you're manually adding dates to `$holidays` every year (this is not elegant.) Notice how I left the year out so it would work every year without any intervention? Good practice would be to do the same thing for these other kind of dates. Not necessary, but a "nice to have"

Comment: You are correct. But the application relies on the client enter off days already. I am not to terrible worried about it, but I do understand where you are coming from, maybe make a third check for off days and keep holidays alone.

Comment: I would suggest using `isset` with a pseudo-map instead of `in_array`.  The former is O(1) and the latter is O(n).

Comment: @NobleUplift I accepted your edit but kept my original code and appended yours to demonstrate the solution easily for future readers. Micro optimization is trivial when it's not the purpose of the question being asked.

Comment: The code doesn't work if the start date ($date) is a holiday, though.

Comment: @TheJakester The definition of the question is the **next** _three working dates_. The current date is not applicable and not considered even if it wasn't a holiday. For example if it's Dec 26th (Boxing Day) and I wanted the next 3 working dates, the 27th, 28th, and 29th would be valid return responses. If the starting date was Dec 25th, I would get the 27th, 28th, and the 29th still. (All assuming the 27th, 28th, and 29th are not weekend dates.)

Comment: You're right. I was trying to adapt the code to calculate the end date from a start date and a length of working days, but your answer totally works for the original question.

Comment: In 2020, the solution does **NOT** work, as is. It throws the following error: **Warning: DateTime::add() expects parameter 1 to be DateInterval, string given in...**. To fix this, replace the line `$nextDay->add('P1D');` with `$nextDay->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));`

Comment: @Devner Thanks, I've edited the answer based on your comment and [this documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) - the string parameter probably broke on PHP 7.

Comment: @sjagr Thanks for the edit, but seems like you missed making the same update for the 2nd code block. Please update it when you get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: @sjagr I performed some tests using your function and looks like it does **NOT** consider Leap Year. For example, the current year i.e. 2020 is a leap year and that causes a difference in calculating the business days. If you look at the calendar, Feb 29, 2020 is a Saturday!!! It appears that Feb 29, 2020 is considered as a working day whereas the actual working day is on the following Monday. So here, it needs to add 2 more days to the total, especially because Feb 29, 2020 is a Saturday. So if your function could be made to consider even a leap year, then I think it would be perfect!

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19221403/67332) of how to get number of working days between 2 dates; which you can simply modify to fit your needs:

```php
function number_of_working_dates($from, $days) {
    $workingDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; # date format = N (1 = Monday, ...)
    $holidayDays = ['*-12-25', '*-01-01', '2013-12-24', '2013-12-25']; # variable and fixed holidays

    $from = new DateTime($from);
    $dates = [];
    $dates[] = $from->format('Y-m-d');
    while ($days) {
        $from->modify('+1 day');

        if (!in_array($from->format('N'), $workingDays)) continue;
        if (in_array($from->format('Y-m-d'), $holidayDays)) continue;
        if (in_array($from->format('*-m-d'), $holidayDays)) continue;

        $dates[] = $from->format('Y-m-d');
        $days--;
    }
    return $dates;
}

print_r( number_of_working_dates('2013-12-23', 3) );
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/90006)</kbd>

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. 

I want to generate `$holidayDays` variable from database like that 

`$qry_hk = "SELECT holiday FROM dim_holiday_dates";
$result_hk = mysqli_query($db,$qry_hk);

$holidayDays = [while ($data_hk = mysqli_fetch_array($result_hk)) {echo '"'.$data_hk['holiday'].'",';}]; `

but error  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ']' in`

help me